# Can I use visitor pattern with @vue/compiler-dom?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to modify(add or remove node) the parsed ast return by the `parse` function of `@vue/compiler-dom`.

I would expect there is a `visit` method of the ast object, but I can't find one.

Here is the pseudo code what I would expect:

`foo.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>
    <a href="">
      bar
      <img src="" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div @click="onClick">foobar</div>
</template>

<script lang="js">
export default {
  methods: {
    onClick () {},
  },
}
</script>
```

```
import { parse } from '@vue/compiler-dom';

const ast = parse(content of foo.vue)

ast.visit(...)
```